# Some EXIF metadata won't update in Swift

Tags: swift, exif

I'm trying to update the metadata of an image but I'm having mixed success. From examples I've found on blogs and Stack Overflow I think I'm doing the correct thing but some values will update, whereas others won't. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong please?

```swift
    func writeMetadata(originalImage url: URL) {

        let newDestinationPath = NSTemporaryDirectory().appending("Out.jpg")
        let newDestinationURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: newDestinationPath)

        // Create source and destination
        guard let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url),
              let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(imageData as CFData, nil),
              let utf = CGImageSourceGetType(imageSource),
              let destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(newDestinationURL as CFURL, utf, 1, nil) else { return }

        // Get original metadata
        guard let originalImageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil) as? NSDictionary,
              let mutableDictionary = originalImageProperties.mutableCopy() as? NSMutableDictionary,
              let exifDictionary = mutableDictionary[kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary as String] as? NSMutableDictionary else { return }
        print("Original metadata: \(originalImageProperties)")

        // These properties successfully update
        exifDictionary["CameraOwnerName"] = "ADB"
        exifDictionary["ApertureValue"] = 1

        // This property doesn't update
        print("Date Before: \(exifDictionary[kCGImagePropertyExifDateTimeDigitized as String])")
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss"
        exifDictionary[kCGImagePropertyExifDateTimeDigitized as String] = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
        print("Date After: \(exifDictionary[kCGImagePropertyExifDateTimeDigitized as String])")

        // Update original metadata with updated Exif dictionary
        mutableDictionary[kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary as String] = exifDictionary

        // Write new file
        CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource(destination, imageSource, 0, mutableDictionary as CFDictionary)
        CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination)

        // Fetch updated metadata
        guard let newSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(newDestinationURL as CFURL, nil),
              let newMetadata = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(newSource, 0, nil) else { return }
        print("Newly updated metadata: \(newMetadata)")
    }
```

Any guidance much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code, which is running fine and the `EXIF` data updated as expected for `DateTimeDigitized`. Would it be possible that you checked the `DateTimeOriginal` metadata or `{TIFF}` metadata instead, which you are not updating?

If you want to set the `DateTimeOriginal` metadata, it can be done as below using the key `kCGImagePropertyExifDateTimeOriginal`

```
exifDictionary[kCGImagePropertyExifDateTimeOriginal as String] = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
```

Comment: Thanks for checking. Strangely, the file I was originally using doesn't update but I tried a handful of other files and they did - so it must be something weird with the original file.